# Databricks access to files not using SPARK sc

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I uploaded a file to Databricks successfully.

```
/FileStore/tables/DEL2018_05.txt
```

Using **sc.textFile** no issue to process.

However, none of the other methods inside the Databricks notebook return anything except for dbutils. I looked at the documentation, but I can't figure it out. If I write a normal Scala program for file processing, things work as well.

Why does:

```
val d = new File("/FileStore/tables/")
d.listFiles
```

return nothing?

```
d: java.io.File = DBFS/FileStore/tables
res51: Array[java.io.File] = null
```

In addition, running this SCALA in DataBricks Notebook:

```
Source.fromFile("/FileStore/customGerard/ALT2018_01.txt").mkString
```

returns:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /FileStore/customGerard/ALT2018_01.txt (No such file or directory)
```

but using dbutils the file I can observe as being there. A big mystery at this point in time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For community edition, the best way is using this command:

`display(dbutils.fs.ls("/FileStore/tables/"))`

where `/FileStore/tables/` is your path

Answer (score 3):

Need **/dbfs**

```
val d = new File("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/")
```

works then!!!

Databricks documentation not clear imho.